# Assigning a variable to a cookie.. no wait! The other way around

Tags: jquery, html, css, cookies

I would like to assign a cookie to a variable...

e.g. 
   `var aVariable = $.cookie("moo");`

I am using the [jQuery cookie functions](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) - do I need to set the cookie AND set the variable at the same time or something?

Help pretty please!

^.^

My Code:

```
function goBackToPosition() {
    var xPos = $.cookie("yourPositionX");
    var yPos = $.cookie("yourPositionY");

        console.log(xPos);
        console.log(yPos);

    if (xPos) {
        alert("xpos!");
        $(this).animate({
            top:    yPos,
            left:   xPos
    }, 400, function(){
            $.cookie("yourPositionX", null);
            $.cookie("yourPositionY", null);
    });

    }
}
```

I get the following error: `a.ownerDocument is undefined`

Comment: You're passing a function insted of an object to `css()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong here:

```
$(this).css(function() {
    top:    yPos,
    left:   xPos
}, 400, function() {
    $.cookie("yourPositionX", null);
    $.cookie("yourPositionY", null);
});
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
$(this).css({
    top:    yPos,
    left:   xPos
}).fadeIn(400, function(){
    $.cookie("yourPositionX", null);
    $.cookie("yourPositionY", null);
});
```

Or:

```
$(this).animate({
    top:    yPos,
    left:   xPos
}, 400, function(){
    $.cookie("yourPositionX", null);
    $.cookie("yourPositionY", null);
});
```

**In response to your update / new issue:**

`$(this)` will not work in the scope of `goBackToPosition` as this references that function, rather than an element. You will have to change `$(this)` to `$('selector')` to get it to work.

Or use `goBackToPosition.call($('selector'))` if you would like to keep using this.
The call function alters the value of this when the called function executes, a similar function is `apply`.

Comment: Ok, so that got rid of that error. The problem I have is that I tried the animate() function before and I get this error (even with your code): `a.ownerDocument is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`this` is meaningless in that context. Either replace it with a selector, or give it some meaning:

```
jQuery.fn.goBackToPosition = function() {
    var xPos = $.cookie("yourPositionX");
    var yPos = $.cookie("yourPositionY");

        console.log(xPos);
        console.log(yPos);

    if (xPos) {
        alert("xpos!");
        this.animate({
            top:    yPos,
            left:   xPos
        }, 400, function(){
                $.cookie("yourPositionX", null);
                $.cookie("yourPositionY", null);
        });

    }
}
```

So then:

```
$(selector).goBackToPosition()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might mean.

```
 $(this).css({
            top:    yPos,
            left:   xPos
        }).fadeIn(400, function() {
            $.cookie("yourPositionX", null);
            $.cookie("yourPositionY", null);
        });
```

The syntax you had didn't make sense.  You were passing a function, but the body of the function looked like an object literal.  As balupton said, you may need to combine with `fadeIn`.

```
{
   top:    yPos,
   left:   xPos
}
```

is the same as:

```
{
   "top":    yPos,
   "left":   xPos
}
```

It creates an object with top and left properties with the values `yPos` and `xPos`, respectively.